# Remove Class using Javascript inside of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to remove a class of a certain element (#main-content) on a single page using Javascript. The page was written in PHP, but from what I can find, Javascript is the easiest method for removing the class. I referenced the post: [How can I insert javascript in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025326/how-can-i-insert-javascript-in-php) and [RemoveClass AddClass When Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570852/removeclass-addclass-when-page-load) to help me come up with the following solution:

```
<? php echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $(\"section#main-content\").removeClass(\"trans-header\");
        });</script>';
?>
```

I validated this code and placed it at the top of my page but it doesn't seem to work. What might I be missing? (Also if it helps, here is the page I am trying to apply the code to: http://7a9.007.myftpupload.com/contact/)

Comment: No need to escape `"`, since they are enclosed using `'`. Also, do you have jQuery included before this script appears?

Comment: did you look to see where it's adding the js? It's putting it before `html` and you're escaping the `"` when you don't need to like @Enstage mentioned.

Comment: If the page is generated in PHP, why don't you alter the PHP to simply not include the class in the first place, instead of fighting a Javascript battle with your own site within the user's browser?

Comment: I can see Jquery is being loaded on page just by inspecting it but I'm not sure from where. I am modifying a theme another developer created so I'm not sure how to tell where it is being loaded from... I assumed it was pulling from the header() ? The page I'm modifying is a template that is referencing a separate header file with the class. I only want this template/page with the header to be modified not every page with the header.

Comment: I tried it without the \ escaping and I kept getting an error to say that it was expecting a "," or a ";" in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead, you don't need jQuery. And add this either somewhere in `<head></head>` or within `<body></body>` - not above `html` as it is currently.

```
<?php echo '<script>document.getElementById("main-content").classList.remove("trans-header");</script>' ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I placed this at the bottom just before the footer and it works! I wasn't understanding where the proper placement was for this.

Comment: @KristinP awesome, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a wordpress site... replace all `$` with `jQuery`.

Also, check your console to see there's another error on the page.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to replace with jQuery but that did not seem to work. I did see there was another error on the page, but I'm not sure how to address that either. Something built-in to the theme code I suspect.

Comment: Ít probably was due to escaping, but I see you got it fixed.